# Jpa and spring 3 mvc validation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, validation

I am working with spring 3 mvc and I need to do the validation with it.

Actually the validator is not working and I can't understand the reason.

I do the next configuration:

In the pom.xml I add the next dependency:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
     <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
 </dependency>
```

I do the productsForm.jsp and add the tag:

```
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
```

I add the tags:  `<form:form>` and `<form:input>`.

I write the follow in the controller:

```
//Here is to show the form

@RequestMapping(value = "Products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String ManagmentHome(Map model2,Model model,HttpServletRequest request){
    Product validationForm=new Product();  
    model2.put("validationForm",validationForm);
    return "productsForm";
}

// Here is to process the form

public String addProduct(@RequestParam String product,  BindingResult result, Map model2,Model model, HttpServletRequest request,@Valid Product validationForm) {

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "productsForm";
     }
}
```

I am using Ajax to get the params.

If I do not use the validator it works fine, but when I use the validator it does not work, it show me  an 400 (Bad Request) When I submit the form.

I do not what the problem is. Can you help me?
Have you any example ?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your controller have @RequestMapping with Ajax Header?

For example, in the controller :

```
 public static final String AJAX = "X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest";
 @RequestMapping(value = "/url", 
  method = RequestMethod.GET,headers=  AJAX)
  public String someMethod(argument1, ....){...}
```

Also, I recommend put a break point to check if request gets mapped by the Controller.